# Transplanting Javascript application to iOS/Android flutter

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter

I have browser application which uses `javascript`,`node.js`,`jquery`,`HTML5(canvas)`.

Now I want to transplant this application to `iOS/Android`.

I am familiar with making iOS/Android application by flutter, so I know that it is possible to make `iOS/Android/webapp` from `dart` code.

However for vice-versa??? is there any way to make iOS/Android from HTML5??

Flutter is best but ,any other way???

For example on `Titanaium`, is it possible to make application by Javascript.

But, it means language is javascript but no library like jquery doesn't work.

So my idea is ,,, use `webview` on `flutter` and use application via this view,, but is it possible???

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache Cordova. Although I'm not a fan of it and I'd advise you to write the application natively (with Java or Kotlin), Cordova is quite known and some apps on the store use it.

https://cordova.apache.org/